# How do I change the string encoding?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, character-encoding

The essence of the task is to Write an application to run under the Android OS that
translates text in the same encoding (for example,`win-1251`) and writes
content in a different encoding (for example, `utf-8`) and the reverse task.

When entering a message, I don't touch the encoding at all.
Then I just process a simple tap and a long tap to change the encoding.
In other words, if you enter just text, everything works correctly.
When you normally click, the `ConvertItem` method is called
If you click for a long time, the `ConvertItem2` method is called
I tried this

```
const convertItem = (text,key) =>{
    var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
    const buf = Buffer.from(text, "binary");
    const str = iconv.decode(buf, "win1251");
    setValue(old=>old.map((value)=>{
        if(value.key==key){
            value.text = str
        }
        return value
    })
}  

const convertItem2 = (text,key) =>{
    var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
    const buf = Buffer.from(text, "binary");
    const str = iconv.decode(buf, "utf8");
    setValue(old=>old.map((value)=>{
        if(value.key==key){
            value.text = str
        }
        return value
    })
}
```

Comment: And what is the issue exactly?

Comment: When you click on a block with text, its encoding should change, and when you click for a long time, it should be decoded. As you can see, the characters are displayed incorrectly.

Comment: "As you can see" we can't see, as you haven't provided examples of expected or actual output. To enable others to help you, describe the exact behavior you expected, as well as how that behavior differs from what is happening with your current implementation.

Comment: My screenshot with the example was deleted. Ok. When I add text, the CreateItem method is called with a simple click, and the text is expected to change its encoding. If you click on the same text for a long time, the CreateItem 2 method is called, and the encoding is expected to change to the original one.
But when entering Russian characters, an invalid result is returned when calling any of the methods. Specifically, Russian characters are displayed incorrectly.
For example, when you enter a text (thousand pysch), when you click on this text, the text changes to ("KI ?KI)